# init: Failed to insmod '/lib/modules/apr.ko' with args '': Exec format error while booting Android

Tags: android, linux-kernel, compilation, dragonboard

I am trying to install Android 13 to RB3 development board. According to [Linaro blog](https://www.linaro.org/blog/android-13-now-available-on-qualcomm-reference-boards-rb5-and-rb3/) this is possible. I followed instrutions on the [Linaro wiki page](https://wiki.linaro.org/AOSP/db845c). So, firstly I compiled kernel :

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/manifest -b common-android-mainline
repo sync -j4
tools/bazel clean
tools/bazel run //common:db845c_dist
```

then, I cloned the Android source code :

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b master
repo sync -j4
```

then, I pasted kernel artifacts into Android source code and compiled Android

```
./device/linaro/dragonboard/fetch-vendor-package.sh
source ./build/envsetup.sh
lunch db845c-userdebug
make TARGET_KERNEL_USE=mainline -j8
```

it was compiled successfly. After, I flashed Android images:

```
./device/linaro/dragonboard/installer/db845c/flash-all-aosp.sh
```

RB3 started to boot after flashing. But an error occured while it was booting :

```
[    3.886126][    T1] init: init first stage started!
[    3.894311][    T1] init: Loading module /lib/modules/apr.ko with args ''
[    3.901376][    T1] apr: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
[    3.908203][    T1] init: Failed to insmod '/lib/modules/apr.ko' with args '': Exec format error
```

I think "Exec format error" is about architecture of the binary file. So output of the `file` command for apr.ko is this :

```
apr.ko: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), BuildID[sha1]=fa4e013385edb783a708df96f0e6834cad9fe0ac, not stripped
```

It seems correct to me. Full boot log is here : https://pastebin.com/XTZWZmD9

then I tried pre-compiled kernel from https://ci.android.com. kernel link is : https://ci.android.com/builds/submitted/10380040/kernel_db845c_kleaf/latest
I pasted kernel artifacts into Android source code and compiled Android as before.

```
./device/linaro/dragonboard/fetch-vendor-package.sh
source ./build/envsetup.sh
lunch db845c-userdebug
make TARGET_KERNEL_USE=mainline -j8
```

now I have again "Exec format error". but there is another error before this line :

```
[    3.914015][    T1] init: init first stage started!
[    3.922358][    T1] init: Loading module /lib/modules/apr.ko with args ''
[    3.929427][    T1] module apr: .gnu.linkonce.this_module section size must match the kernel's built struct module size at run time
[    3.941451][    T1] init: Failed to insmod '/lib/modules/apr.ko' with args '': Exec format error
```

Also output of the `file` command for apr.ko is :

```
apr.ko: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), BuildID[sha1]=398930130c8bea9c488da47636a4f8ae2a2ee413, not stripped
```

Full boot log is here : https://pastebin.com/3KukqxGC

I am very confused about what is wrong here ? How can I install Android 13 on rb3 ?